# Select the save format in the Save As dialog by using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

How do I select the output format in the Save As dialog of Mail.app? I know how to change the file name by using `keystroke` but I could not figure out how to change the file format in AppleScript.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **Mail** has focus and the **Save As** *sheet* is showing, then the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* would click the **Format:** *pop up menu* and select e.g.: **Plain Text**

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Mail"
        tell sheet 1 of window 1
            tell pop up button 2
                click
                click menu item "Plain Text" of menu 1
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

You can also use the *menu item number*, e.g. `click menu item 3 of menu 1`

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

My final scrip is as follows.

```
    tell application "System Events"

        tell process "Mail"
            keystroke "s" using {command down, shift down}
            delay 1
            keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
            delay 1
            keystroke "/tmp/purchase.rtf"
            click button "Go" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of the front window
            click pop up button 2 of sheet 1 of the front window
            click menu item "Rich Text Format" of menu 1 of pop up button 2 of sheet 1 of the front window
            click button "Save" of sheet 1 of the front window
            try
                click UI element "Replace" of sheet 1 of sheet 1 of the front window
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with key presses and clicks? You can tell Mail to `save message in file as saveable file format`.